# abode acrobat reader with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, com

I am trying to display a PDF in an Adobe PDF reader COM component in VB.NET.

All i do is:

```
   AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile("file path here")
```

But for some reason it's not displaying the PDF.

Can someone please advise me on what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `axAcroPDF1.Show()`

According to the documentation you need a control for each new file you load, they aren't completely re-usable.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did the .show as well but still it does not display the pdf. Please advise

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't really provide much more help.

Check the initialization of the control, and make sure the control is setup correctly in the WinForm.

Comment: I am able to view the pdf file by using the below code 

AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile(fileDialog.FileName)
AxAcroPDF1.Show()

But the problem is when i select any file other then PDF for example a JPG file then it shows an error which is fine but then if i try selecting another PDF file it never shows that. Please advise

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to create a new instance of the viewer.  As stated the control isn't re-usable for some unknown reason.